# How to get WPA2 working on Eee 701?

Tags: linux, eee-pc

How can I get WPA2 support on an Eee PC 701 with the default Linux-based OS? I found Google references to a file named SOP_for_701_WIFI_installation.zip but the download doesn't work.

I also found other information saying that I'm supposed to get an update via the OS's update manager, but I have to be online to do this! Given that I have a WPA2 connection at home, how am I supposed to get online to update?

Comment: The simple solution is to disable WPA2 authentication until you can get online and download the updates then enable it.  Your "link" is just a random filename doesn't really help.

Comment: @Ramhound, if you post that as an answer I'd vote for it.  I don't know if an Eee 701 has an Ethernet port but that might be useful too.